# WebSphere MQ .NET - How to test locally?

Tags: .net, testing, ibm-mq

Any ideas how (if I) can I test WebSphere MQ locally using the IBM.XMS library without installing a MQ server (i.e. with just the MQ Client) whether it's via a simulator, mocks or local message queue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options. You can use a WebSphere MQ queue manager to test applications written using IBM.XMS or any other MQ client.  You can download a trial copy from developerWorks [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/ws/wmq/).  The trial version is fully enabled and good for 90 days.

IBM.XMS can also be used for messaging with Default Messaging Provider of WebSphere Application Server.  You can download a WAS trial [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/downloads/).

Comment: These days you can also use the free IBM MQ for Developers https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/mq/